# Printing Different Patterns in Single Program

Tags: c#

Are there solutions for the following problem?

> A user enters an X coordinate, Y coordinate, length, and (optional)
>   number. If a number was entered, print a straight line with the
>   specified length, followed by the (x,y) coordinates. If n=2, print
>   bisecting lines with the specified length. If n=3, print a triangle
>   where the lines are the specified length.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Wait, are in the middle of an interview?

Comment: @PavanThatavarthi What do you mean by "print" a line? Do you mean to use a graphics library or to use ASCII?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want ASCII drawings, here's how this would work. Note that I'm just providing an outline of how this would work, since I don't want to answer the interview question for you. Also, this is **not production-quality** since there's no validation (or differentiation between lack of input and invalid input).

First, let's ask the user for their input. `Console.ReadLine` is how you do this. Since we'll be getting input four times, let's make it a method. The return type can be `int` since everything we're getting from the user is a number. We'll print the prompt (passed in as an argument) with `Console.WriteLine` and then return the result of `Console.ReadLine` after converting it to an `int` (do you need validation)? Since `n` is optional, maybe return something like `-1` if the user doesn't enter anything.

Store the results so that we can use them later in our calculations. Use an `if... else if` (or `switch`) statement to determine if `n` was supplied by the user and take action accordingly. We can call different methods depending on whether we want to draw a line, two bisecting lines, or a triangle.

Is the actual drawing the problem? I'm having trouble understand exactly where you need help, and the drawing of the shapes would be more complicated. For now, though, this should get you on the right track.